# "await is only valid in async functions" while it's an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, arrow-functions

I'm getting this error for some reason:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

I've no idea what's wrong with it. It's obviously an async function.

```
const muteCheckTimer = async (client) => {
setInterval(() => { 
    db.each(query, [], (err, row) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if(row) {
            let currentTimestamp = Date.now();
            if(currentTimestamp > row.mutedTimestamp) {
                let user = await client.users.fetch(row.userID);
                if(!user.member) { console.log('Not a user') }

                let MutedRole = user.member.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === "Muted");
                if(!MutedRole) { console.log("Muted role doesn't exists") }
                
                //await user.member.roles.remove(MutedRole);
                
            } else {
                console.log('MUTED');
            }

        }

    });
}, 10000);
```

}

Comment: Neither `() => {` nor `(err, row) => {` are marked as `async`.

Comment: Doesn't look like `muteCheckTimer` needs to be `async` however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner function is not async.